# How to pass data as navigation props (not working)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Initially startDate and untilDate is undefined when user clicks on filter option calendar opens up and user selects startDate and untilDate which is passed again back to previous screen when user clicks on apply button. But initially API endpoint URL : `/api` and when user gets back to previous screen on selecting startDate and untilDate then API endpoint changes to `/api&start_date=${startDate}&end_date=${untilDate}` but the data is not getting fetched again with new api endpoint i.e with startDate and endDate.

Code:

visit.js:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Filter')}>
      <Image source={require('../assets/filter.png')} style={{width: 24, height: 24, marginRight: 15, resizeMode: 'contain'}}/>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

`API request is made in below code and above code is filter button which opens up calendar`

```
getLeadSiteVisitReports = () => {

        const startDate = this.props.navigation.getParam('startDate');

        const untilDate = this.props.navigation.getParam('untilDate');

        API.getLeadSiteVisitReportsForProject(this.props.logged_in_user, this.props.current_project, startDate, untilDate)
        .then((res) => {
            this.setState({ leadsitevisits: res });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error in getLeadSiteVisitReportsForProject", err);
        });
    }

    componentWillMount = () => {
        this.getLeadSiteVisitReports();
    }
```

Iniside fetch-data.js:

```
export const getLeadSiteVisitReportsForProject = (logged_in_user, project, startDate, untilDate) => {

  if (startDate === undefined && untilDate === undefined){
      const URL = API_URL + `/lead_site_visit_report?user=${logged_in_user.id}&project=${project.id}`;  
      console.log("getLeadSiteVisitReportsForProject: ", URL);
      return fetchGet(URL);

  } else {
      const URL = API_URL + `/lead_site_visit_report?user=${logged_in_user.id}&project=${project.id}&start_date=${startDate}&end_date=${untilDate}`;
      console.log("getLeadSiteVisitReportsForProject: ", URL);
      return fetchGet(URL);
  }

}
```

So default data is fetched but when startDate and untilDate is selected that time data is not fetched by making call to another API endpoint see above `getLeadSiteVisitReportsForProject`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this has solved your problem completely. Its always better to understand react lifecycle properly before using it. It will always help you out.

getLeadSiteVisitReports = () => {

```
    const startDate = this.props.navigation.getParam('startDate');

    const untilDate = this.props.navigation.getParam('untilDate');

    console.log("Before making GET req: ", startDate);
    console.log("Before making GET req: ", untilDate);


    API.getLeadSiteVisitReportsForProject(this.props.logged_in_user, this.props.current_project, startDate, untilDate)
    .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ leadsitevisits: res });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error in getLeadSiteVisitReportsForProject", err);
    });
}

componentWillMount = () => {
    // TODO: Get lead site visits
    this.getLeadSiteVisitReports();
}

componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState) => {
    console.log("Previos props : ",prevProps);
    console.log("props: ", this.props);
    if(this.props && this.props.navigation && this.props.navigation.state && 
       this.props.navigation.state.params && 
       this.props.navigation.state.params.startDate) {
        // call your api here.
        this.getLeadSiteVisitReports();
        console.log("End end end end end end end end");
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use `willFocus` method from `react-navigation`,
for example in your `componentDidMount()`

```
componentDidMount() {
this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', () => {
this.getLeadSiteVisitReports();
 }),
}
```

assuming you always receive the updated time and date, and if you want to make sure you always get the right date, you can `console.log()` inside `willFocus` to check your data.

UPDATE, If this doesn't solve your issue you can just check for date change inside your `componentDidUpdate`

for example

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
 if(prevState.startDate !== this.state.startDate | prevState.untilDate !== this.state.untilDate) {
  // call your api here.
  this.getLeadSiteVisitReports();
  }
}
```

here, first check if your `startDate` and `untillDate` changed, if so, then call the api.

Comment: Initially startDate and untilDate is undefined. So date of all days is shown see screenshot 1. Now when user adds filter by selecting startDate and untilDate I am passing that from calendar component to previous screen using navigation props. Now when startDate and untilDate is not undefined it should make request to new API endpoint and load the data